# copy command in cassandra execution order

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I am copying csv file to cassandra. I have the below csv file and the table is created as below.

CREATE TABLE UCBAdmissions(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    admit text,
    dept text,
    freq int,
    gender text
)

1. When I use

   > copy UCBAdmissions from 'UCBAdmissions.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ',' AND HEADER = TRUE;

The output is
24 rows imported in 0.318 seconds.
cqlsh> select *from UCBAdmissions;

id | admit | dept | freq | gender
----+-------+------+------+--------

(0 rows)

2. > copy UCBAdmissions(id,admit,gender, dept , freq )from 'UCBAdmissions.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ',' AND HEADER = TRUE;

The output is
24 rows imported in 0.364 seconds.
cqlsh> select *from UCBAdmissions;

id | admit    | dept | freq | gender
----+----------+------+------+--------
 23 | Admitted |    F |   24 | Female
  5 | Admitted |    B |  353 |   Male
 10 | Rejected |    C |  205 |   Male
 16 | Rejected |    D |  244 | Female
 13 | Admitted |    D |  138 |   Male
 11 | Admitted |    C |  202 | Female
  1 | Admitted |    A |  512 |   Male
 19 | Admitted |    E |   94 | Female
  8 | Rejected |    B |    8 | Female
  2 | Rejected |    A |  313 |   Male
  4 | Rejected |    A |   19 | Female
 18 | Rejected |    E |  138 |   Male
 15 | Admitted |    D |  131 | Female
 22 | Rejected |    F |  351 |   Male
 20 | Rejected |    E |  299 | Female
  7 | Admitted |    B |   17 | Female
  6 | Rejected |    B |  207 |   Male
  9 | Admitted |    C |  120 |   Male
 14 | Rejected |    D |  279 |   Male
 21 | Admitted |    F |   22 |   Male
 17 | Admitted |    E |   53 |   Male
 24 | Rejected |    F |  317 | Female
 12 | Rejected |    C |  391 | Female
  3 | Admitted |    A |   89 | Female

UCBAdmissions.csv

"","Admit","Gender","Dept","Freq"
"1","Admitted","Male","A",512
"2","Rejected","Male","A",313
"3","Admitted","Female","A",89
"4","Rejected","Female","A",19
"5","Admitted","Male","B",353
"6","Rejected","Male","B",207
"7","Admitted","Female","B",17
"8","Rejected","Female","B",8
"9","Admitted","Male","C",120
"10","Rejected","Male","C",205
"11","Admitted","Female","C",202
"12","Rejected","Female","C",391
"13","Admitted","Male","D",138
"14","Rejected","Male","D",279
"15","Admitted","Female","D",131
"16","Rejected","Female","D",244
"17","Admitted","Male","E",53
"18","Rejected","Male","E",138
"19","Admitted","Female","E",94
"20","Rejected","Female","E",299
"21","Admitted","Male","F",22
"22","Rejected","Male","F",351
"23","Admitted","Female","F",24
"24","Rejected","Female","F",317

I see the output order getting changed from the csv file as seen above.
Question: What is the difference between 1 and 2? Should we follow the same order as of csv file to create the table in cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is designed to be distributed - to accomplish this, it uses the partition key of your table (`id`) and hashes it using the cluster's partitioner (probably `Murmur3Partitioner`) to create an integer (actually a Long), and then uses that integer to assign it to a node in the ring.

What you're seeing are the results ordered by the resulting token, which is non-intuitive, but not necessarily wrong. There is no straight-forward way to do a `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY primaryKey ASC` in Cassandra - the distributed nature makes that difficult to do effectively.